# Symfony2 form repeated field - how to move 'not matching' message to confirm field?

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm creating a sign-up type of form and within that I use a 'repeated' field type to get the user's desired password and confirm it. I add this field to my form like this:

```
$builder->add(
    'password',
    'repeated',
    array(
        'first_options'  => array('label' => 'user.form.password.label'),
        'second_options' => array('label' => 'user.form.password_confirm.label'),
        'invalid_message' => 'user.password_confirm.not_matched',
        'type' => 'password',
    )
);
```

This works fine - except that when the passwords do not match the 'does not match' error message is displayed with the first field (the password field) rather than with the second, confirm, field. It seems to me that it's much more logical to have this message appear with the confirm field - but I'm struggling to find a way to achieve this?

I thought that perhaps the 'error_mapping' option was what I needed, but I've not managed to make that work and I'm not sure if that is the right direction for me to be looking in or not?

Thanks for any help,
Matt

Comment: Render field by hand can be solution at this situation. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand

Comment: I am rendering the field by hand anyway - though I'm not sure that it helps with this actual problem. I need to have errors such as a password not being entered at all to be put with the first field, and errors such as confirm field not matching put with that field.

Comment: I ended up working around this for now by not using the repeated field type at all; instead I created two password fields and compared them myself. I still feel that it would be better if I could make use of the repeated field type to do this though.

Answer (score 5):

if anyone still interested how it can be done sf2 2.7 (i dont check older versions)

```
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', [
            'type' => 'password',
            'invalid_message' => 'user.password_repeat.not_match',
            'error_mapping' => [
                '.' => 'second'
            ]
        ])
```

So i hope it will be helpful because google search results for this task still lead to this question without proper answer

Comment: this is awesome. i searched for that an hour now.

Comment: Does anyone know how I could make only the none matching error to be mapped to the second field ?

Answer (score 2):

Move a confirm field to the first option:

```
$builder->add(
    'password',
    'repeated',
    array(
        'second_options'  => array('label' => 'user.form.password.label'),
        'first_options' => array('label' => 'user.form.password_confirm.label'),
        'invalid_message' => 'user.password_confirm.not_matched',
        'type' => 'password',
    )
);
```

and change the fields order in the template

```
{{ form_row(form.password.second) }}
{{ form_row(form.password.first) }}
```